# Certain related lists are not displaying on Field Service mobile app

Tags: fsl

Certain related lists are not displaying on the Field Service mobile app.

- When I access an Asset - Work Orders & Cases related lists do not show
- When accessing an Account - Work Orders, Cases, & Assets do not show

All displays ok when logging in as the same technician users on desktop and regular salesforce mobile app.